# What does it indicate when a table spool has more than one

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

[image: Table spool]

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181032.aspx),

> The Table Spool operator scans the input and places a copy of each row in a hidden spool table that is stored in the tempdb database and existing only for the lifetime of the query.

First, there's no input in the plan before this step...  This text indicates that it should and [other resources](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/operator-of-the-week---spools,-eager-spool/) online have said as much.

> The spool operators are always used together with another operator. As it stores values, it needs to know what these values are, and so it must receive them from another operator.

Second, when the output list in the hover over contains more than one table. Are all of them being spooled to individual tables? and if so, why not show multiple steps? If they are all being spooled to one table, are they being joined prior to the spooling? A 'flattening' out of the tables, if you will.

Third, as I explain below I think I have an answer for 1 and 2... but now I see the cost % for the original step is 0% and when that spool is reused in another branch the cost % is 12%. Why would reading it back cost more than the original writing out?

EDIT : Text Plan

```
StmtText
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY]=[Expr1021], [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY]=[Expr1022], [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE]=[Expr1023], [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY]=[Expr1024], [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]=[Expr1025]))
       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Expr1021], [Expr1022], [Expr1023], [Expr1024], [Expr1025])=([Expr1016], [Expr1017], [Expr1018], [Expr1019], [Expr1020]), RESIDUAL:([Expr1016] = [Expr1021] AND [Expr1017] = [Expr1022] AND [Expr1018] = [Expr1023] AND [Expr1019] = [Expr1024] AND [Expr1020] = [Expr1025]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1021]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY], [Expr1022]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY], [Expr1023]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[WEEK_END_DATE] as [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE], [Expr1024]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY], [Expr1025]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] as [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]))
            |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1011]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1059],0)))
            |         |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY], [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY], [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE], [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY], [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]) DEFINE:([Expr1059]=COUNT([Expr1015])))
            |              |--Sort(DISTINCT ORDER BY:([so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] ASC, [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] ASC, [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE] ASC, [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] ASC, [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] ASC, [Expr1015] ASC))
            |                   |--Table Spool
            |                        |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1015]=[Expr1013]+[Expr1014]))
            |                             |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([so].[SLS_ORG_GK])=([f].[SLS_ORG_GK]), RESIDUAL:([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[SLS_ORG_GK] as [f].[SLS_ORG_GK]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_GK] as [so].[SLS_ORG_GK]))
            |                                  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SYS_SLS_ORG_GK] AS [so]))
            |                                  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([c].[CONTR_GK])=([f].[CONTR_GK]), RESIDUAL:([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[CONTR_GK] as [f].[CONTR_GK]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CONTRACTOR].[CONTR_GK] as [c].[CONTR_GK]))
            |                                       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1014]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(38,0),[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CONTRACTOR].[CONTR_SRC_KEY] as [c].[CONTR_SRC_KEY],0)))
            |                                       |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CONTRACTOR].[nc_csk] AS [c]))
            |                                       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([r].[REQ_POS_GK])=([f].[REQ_POS_GK]), RESIDUAL:([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[REQ_POS_GK] as [f].[REQ_POS_GK]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_REQUISITION_POS].[REQ_POS_GK] as [r].[REQ_POS_GK]))
            |                                            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1013]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(38,0),[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_REQUISITION_POS].[REQ_POS_JOB_REQ_SRC_KEY] as [r].[REQ_POS_JOB_REQ_SRC_KEY],0)+[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_REQUISITION_POS].[REQ_POS_POSITION_NO] as [r].[REQ_POS_POSITION_NO]))
            |                                            |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_REQUISITION_POS].[SYS_C00600262] AS [r]))
            |                                            |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([cal].[DATE_GK])=([f].[WEEK_END_DATE_GK]), RESIDUAL:([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[WEEK_END_DATE_GK] as [f].[WEEK_END_DATE_GK]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[DATE_GK] as [cal].[DATE_GK]))
            |                                                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[SYS_C00599872] AS [cal]), WHERE:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[FULL_DATE] as [cal].[FULL_DATE]>=getdate()-'1900-01-31 00:00:00.000'))
            |                                                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[PK_FCT_PRDCR_SPRD_HRS] AS [f]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1016]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY], [Expr1017]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY], [Expr1018]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[WEEK_END_DATE] as [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE], [Expr1019]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY], [Expr1020]=[DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] as [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]))
                 |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY], [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY], [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE], [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY], [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]), RESIDUAL:([DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] = [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_OPR_UNT_SRC_KEY] AND [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] = [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_PROD_SRC_KEY] AND [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[WEEK_END_DATE] as [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE] = [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_CALENDAR].[WEEK_END_DATE] as [cal].[WEEK_END_DATE] AND [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] = [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] as [so].[SLS_ORG_EMPL_SRC_KEY] AND [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] as [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] = [DMRPT].[dbo].[DIM_SALES_ORG].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE] as [so].[SLS_ORG_JOBCODE]) DEFINE:([Expr1010]=SUM([DMRPT].[dbo].[FACT_PRODUCER_SPREAD_HOURS].[SPREAD_LCL] as [f].[SPREAD_LCL])))
                      |--Table Spool
```

Comment: Could you please post the query and the plan in the text format?

Comment: `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

OK well I discovered that if you see that operation to look other places for it in the plan as described [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---lazy-spool/).

So the results of one branch of the plan are written out and the temp table is used again in another branch. So now that I see the source one, I see the predecessors/inputs and see that it's already joined the tables together and is spooling the joined rows.